# error: no matching function for call to ‘min(long unsigned int&, unsigned int&)’

Tags: c++, gcc, ubuntu, boost

I'm using ubuntu 12.04 - 64 bits. I tested it with boost 1.46, 1.48, 1.52 and 
gcc 4.4 and 4.6
When I try to compile:

```
while (m_burstReqBeatsRemain) {
                if (m_burstReqAddress % m_dramRowSize == 0) {
                    m_admRequestQueue.push_back(adm_request());
                    adm_request &req = m_admRequestQueue.back();
                    req.address = m_burstReqAddress;
                    req.command = tlm::TLM_READ_COMMAND;
                    //call to min function
                    req.readLen = std::min(m_burstReqBeatsRemain * sizeof(Td), m_dramRowSize);
                }
                m_burstReqBeatsRemain--;
                m_burstReqAddress += sizeof(Td);
                m_ocpTxnQueue.push_back(m_ocpReq);
}
```

I get this error:

```
no matching function for call to ‘min(long unsigned int&, unsigned int&)
from /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algobase.h*
```

Note: with ubuntu 12.04 32 bits works fine

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: That's because you are trying to take "min" of two different types, and "min" expects both values to be the same type.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

`std::min` is a function template on `T` which is the type of *both*  parameters of the function. But you seem to pass function arguments of different type, *and* rely on template argument deduction from function arguments, which is not possible.

So the fix is :

- Either don't rely on template argument deduction, instead explicitly mention the template argument:

  ```
  std::min<unsigned long>(ulongarg, uintarg); //ok
       //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
       //don't rely on template argument deduction
       //instead pass template argument explicitly.
  ```
- Or pass function arguments of same type:

  ```
  std::min(ulongarg, static_cast<unsigned long>(uintarg)); //ok
                    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                    //pass both arguments of same type
  ```

Comment: @user2008530: That is a compiler bug, or it is a bug in the implementation of `std::min`.

Comment: @user2008530: gcc is being dumb. On that platform `unsigned long` and `unsigned int` are essentially the same type. IMHO, gcc should still be giving you an error, but that's likely why it isn't.

Comment: So probably the behavior of the method in 32-bit version will not be the expected behavior?

Comment: @user2008530: Yes. `unsigned long` and `unsigned int` are two different types, so the compiler should give error.

Answer (score -2):

```
template<typename T,typename T1>T amax(T &a,T1 b){if(b>a)a=b;return a;}
template<typename T,typename T1>T amin(T &a,T1 b){if(b<a)a=b;return a;}
```

Define your template for min and max it will not give error.