# Why this function overloading fails in C++?

Tags: c++, overloading

```
#include <iostream>


int min(int a, int b){
    return a < b ? a : b;
}

long long min(long long a, long long b){
    return a < b ? a : b;
}

int main(){
    int a = 1;
    long long b = 2;
    std::cout<<min(a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile error:

> test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: test.cpp:15:19: error: call of
>   overloaded ‘min(int&, long long int&)’ is ambiguous
>        cout<

But why the `long long min(long long a, long long b)` is not inferred automatically?

Auto cast `int a` to `long long a` would not make it worse at all?

---

```
#include <iostream>

long long min(long long a, long long b){
    return a < b ? a : b;
}

int main(){
    int a = 1;
    long long b = 2;
    std::cout<<min(a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

This one will work without compiling error.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

int main(){
    int a = 1;
    long long b = 2;
    std::cout<<std::min(a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

> In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/algorithm:62:0,
>                    from test.cpp:2: /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:4226:5: note: template _Tp std::min(std::initializer_list<_Tp>, _Compare)
>        min(initializer_list<_Tp> __l, _Compare __comp)
>        ^ /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:4226:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed: test.cpp:8:29: note:
>   mismatched types ‘std::initializer_list<_Tp>’ and ‘int’
>        std::cout<

Comment: Whatever you do, [don't say `using namespace std`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). I wonder who teaches people that.

Comment: Past integral promotions, all integral conversions are one "rule". That's just how it is.

Comment: **Template it.** It'll make your problems go away. :)

Comment: Why even the `std::min` fails as well?

Comment: @Kamel, this may be helpful: [error: no matching function for call to ‘min(long unsigned int&, unsigned int&)’](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14508022/error-no-matching-function-for-call-to-minlong-unsigned-int-unsigned-int)

Comment: @Kamel, Template argument deduction doesn't take conversions into account. One template parameter can't match two types.