# Why less than operator accepts different types of params while std::min not?

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int a = 1;
    long long b = 2;
    std::cout<<(a<b);
    std::cout<<std::min(a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
> In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/char_traits.h:39:0,
>                  from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:40,
>                  from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
>                  from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
>                  from sum_to.cpp:1: /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:239:5: note: template<class
> _Tp, class _Compare> const _Tp& std::min(const _Tp&, const _Tp&, _Compare)
>      min(const _Tp& __a, const _Tp& __b, _Compare __comp)
>      ^ /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:239:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed: sum_to.cpp:7:29:
> note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘const _Tp’ (‘int’ and
> ‘long long int’)
>      std::cout<<std::min(a, b);

---
```

Thanks to [chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/962089/chris) comment in [function overloading post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31935189/why-this-function-overloading-fails-in-c)
  Template argument deduction doesn't take conversions into account. One
  template parameter can't match two types

So `std::min` fail.

Why `<` would work?

Comment: Because it *does* take conversions into account.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because built-in `<` applies [Numeric promotions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast#Numeric_promotions), and template argument deduction doesn't.

Comment: Could you please give reference specific to `<`? I understood `promotions` but cant find out why `<` is suitable for this `promotions`.

Comment: @Kamel It's the case for all built-in arithmetic operators ([link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Conversions)).

Comment: I read Java's document to learn how to use its SDK, while reading C++'s document to learn how its compiler hacks to run the code.

Comment: @Kamel If you mean that C++ is patchy, its not. It's just far more complex than Java, and you need to know more of its pieces to see that they indeed fit together.

Comment: Legacy from C. Call it the curse of backwards compatibility with code going back 3 decades.

Answer (score 3):

As explained in other answers, the reason is that `std::min` requires the types of the arguments to be identical if deduction is to be performed, while `<` implies the usual arithmetic conversions (§5.9/2), which will make sure that the types are converted to a "common denominator". Note how §13.6/12 lists up built-in operators as candidates:

> For every pair of promoted arithmetic types `L` and `R`, there exist
>   candidate operator functions of the form
>
> ```
> // […]
> LR operator<(L , R );
> // […]
> ```
>
> where `LR` is the result of the usual arithmetic conversions between
>   types `L` and `R`.

---

Actually, `std::min` should be able to deal with distinct types. The following is a more modern approach:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr decltype(auto) min(T&& t) {return std::forward<T>(t);}

template <typename T, typename U, typename... Args>
constexpr auto min(T&& t, U&&u, Args&&... args) {
    std::common_type_t<T, U> const& _t(std::forward<T>(t)), _u(std::forward<U>(u));
    return min(_t<_u? _t : _u, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cfc0aa669b076932).

Comment: Isn't `t<u` likely to convert `t` and `u` to `common_type_t<T,U>` (for primitive types)?  Well, it won't make a copy in some cases like your above code will do: that, however, can be fixed with a bit more effort.

Comment: @Yakk I tried something else. However, there might be an `operator<` that compares distinct class types. Then, `a<b? a : b` performs only two copies to `common_type`, while mine performs three in any case. I'm not so bothered about primitive types though, as I expect compilers to optimize accordingly for those.

Comment: If we don't enforce order of `<` (reasonable), and our `min` returns a reference (where possible), then `min(a,b,c...)` being `auto&& x = min(forward(b),forward(c)...); return no_rvalue( a<x)?forward(a):forward(x) );`, where `no_rvalue` converts rvalues to values and leaves lvalues alone?  I guess if `b` is an rvalue and `c...` is empty, this causes an extra copy.  gah.  Need to distinguish between true (local) temporaries, and temporaries passed-in?  To avoid extra copies.

Answer (score 2):

It is because [`std::min`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/min/) is a template function.

> ```
> template <class T> const T& min (const T& a, const T& b) {
>   return !(b<a)?a:b;     // or: return !comp(b,a)?a:b; for version (2)
> }
> ```

so it needs the arguments to have the same type, but if you use `(a<b)`, so `a` could implicitly converted to a `long long`

Answer (score -1):

Primitive types don't overload operators, so *usual arithmetic conversions* are applied and your int is  converted to a long long, and the "<" has a valid meaning.

You can't even overload operators for primitive types:
https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/intrinsic-types#intrinsics-and-operator-overloading

Example to show that your int is promoted to long long

```
// common_type example
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int main() {

  typedef std::common_type<int, long long>::type A;           // i
  std::cout << "A: " << std::is_same<long long,A>::value << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Documentation
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic

> For the binary operators (except shifts), if the promoted operands
>   have different types, additional set of implicit conversions is
>   applied, known as usual arithmetic conversions with the goal to
>   produce the common type (also accessible via the std::common_type type
>   trait)

Comment: Every pair of promoted arithmetic types has operators defined for that pair. `int` is a promoted arithmetic type already. Promotion does not produce anything with a rank greater than `int` unless it doesn't change the type. `int` -> `long long` is not a valid promotion.

Comment: please check my updated answer, I am afraid your comment does not reflect what in reality is happening. "promoted" may have not been the right term, but "usual arithmetic conversions" are applied.

Answer (score -1):

The `<` operator is binary, so the compiler could convert arguments to the same type and compare them.

Otherwise `min` function should return something. How could compiler guess which type should he return?